# Why ASP.NET Core JS colocation requires config but CSS colocation does not?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, razor-pages, asp.net-core-7.0

In an ASP.NET Core Razor Pages (or MVC) project, there is css colocation:

```
Index.cshtml
Index.cshtml.css
```

I don't recall adding configuration for that. I just create a css file and it would be detected and processed during a build.

One can also use js colocation:

```
Index.cshtml
Index.cshtml.js
```

But that requires extra effort in the layout and/or view; for example, in the view:

```html
@section Scripts {
  <script src="~/Pages/Foo/Index.cshtml.js"></script>
}
```

Why does js colocation require extra effort? Is there a way to avoid that manual step?

Comment: I suspect this is a shortcoming of the runtime - if someone can confirm, I'll open a feature request on the repo. I just want to ensure it's not a weird config error on my part.

Comment: I added a [feature request](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/53319) to the repo. Please upvote that if you also want this functionality.

Comment: As [commented on the repo](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/53319#issuecomment-1889648656), they are unwilling to add this functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "feature" you are trying to implement (JS isolation in Razor Pages/ MVC views) doesn't actually exist. It doesn't appear that it ever will be because you can achieve isolation in JS using modules: https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/30850

Comment: The isolation itself is not what I'm after, I want to colocate an old-school non-module js file with a view and for it to be detected without config. But I think you're right - they are thinking about modules instead, and so they didn't allow this use case.